# Powershell - match with Containskey & set value of hashtable don't work

Tags: powershell, hashtable, containskey

I am working on a script by [Richard L. Mueller](http://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShell/PSLastLogon.txt) to disable inactive account in our AD.

```
Trap {"Error: $_"; Break;}

$D = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$Domain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.PageSize = 200
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"

$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("accountExpires") > $Null

# Create hash table of users and their last logon dates.
$arrUsers = @{}

# Enumerate all Domain Controllers.
ForEach ($DC In $D.DomainControllers)
    {
$Server = $DC.Name
$Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$Server/" + $Domain.distinguishedName

$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
#$Results[100].Properties.item("samAccountName")
#$Results[100].Properties.item("lastlogon")
ForEach ($Result In $Results)
    {
        $DN = $Result.Properties.Item("samAccountName")
        $LL = $Result.Properties.Item("lastLogon")
        If ($LL.Count -eq 0)
        {
            $Last = [DateTime]0
        }
        Else
        {
            $Last = [DateTime]$LL.Item(0)
        }
        If ($Last -eq 0)
        {
            $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600)
        }
        Else
        {
            $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600).ToLocalTime()
        }
        If ($arrUsers.ContainsKey("$DN"))
        {
            If ($LastLogon -gt $arrUsers["$DN"])
            {
                $arrUsers["$DN"] = $LastLogon
            }
        }
        Else
        {
            $arrUsers.Add("$DN", $LastLogon)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have the most updated LastLogon date of my AD users.

Then I do:

```
Foreach ($ou in $searchRoot) {
$inactiveUsers += @(Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $ou -Enabled -PasswordNeverExpires:$false -CreatedBefore $creationCutoff -SizeLimit $sizeLimit | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonTimeStamp,Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Sort-Object Name)
}
```

I do not use this to disable the ID because LastLogonTimeStamp has a delay being updated from 9-14 days. And with the real last logon date in $arrUsers, I would like to replace LastLogonTimeStamp with it. So I want to match them using the user ID:

```
Foreach ($inuser in $inactiveUsers) {
    If ($arrUsers.ContainsKey("$inuser.samAccountName"))
        {
        write-host "True"
        $inuser.LastLogonTimeStamp = $arrUsers["$inuser.samAccountName"]
        $inuser.LastLogonTimeStamp = $inuser.LastLogonTimeStamp.adddays(30)
        If ((Get-Date) -gt $inuser.LastLogonTimeStamp)
            {
            write-host $inuser.samAccountName "should be disabled"
            }
        Else
            {
            write-host $inuser.samAccountName "is still active"
            }

        }
    }
    Else
    {
    write-host "False"
    }
```

I have 2 problems here.

1. First the "If ($arrUsers.ContainsKey("$inuser.samAccountName"))" doesn't seems working. I always get a false result.
2. Second, to replace the LastLogonTimeStamp using "$inuser.LastLogonTimeStamp = $arrUsers["$inuser.samAccountName"]", my LastLogonTimeStamp become blank.

Could someone able to provide some assistants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by assign the samAccountName value to another variable:

```
$tmpAccountName = $inuser.samAccountName
```

then

```
If ($arrUsers.ContainsKey("$tmpAccountName"))
```

instead of throw the $inuser.samAccountName directly to the checking. Not so sure why it cannot be read directly however at least it is solved now =). Same goes to the problem #2.

Answer (score 10):

You're not using variable expansion correctly. Object properties aren't expanded, so this

```
"$inuser.samaccountname"
```

is actually:

```
$inuser.ToString() + ".samaccountname"
```

To expand an expression in a string, you must surround it with `$()`, e.g.

```
"$($inuser.samaccountname)"
```

In your case, however, you don't even need to do that. Leave the quotes out entirely:

```
$arrusers[$DN]
$arrusers.ContainsKey($inuser.samaccountname)
```

See the [about_Quoting_Rules help topic for details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx).